# Rename file in Gradle EAR deploy dependency configuration

Tags: java, gradle

I am new in Gradle. Therefore maybe my question is a simple but could not find the way how is possible to rename result file when try to deploy project or artifact into EAR package.
I need delete the version name from the file name template.
For example:

```
dependencies {
    earlib group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version:'3.2.0.RELEASE'
}
```

Result ear will contain file **spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar** into EAR.
But I need **spring-aop.jar** as the result file.

Is there some property of earlib to do it?

Comment: Why do you care about the file name? And why do you prefer a name which makes it hard to know the version of the library? The name of the jar shouldn't matter. Assuming you have a good reason to do that, how do you use this earlib dependency to build your ear?

Comment: Unfortunately I need it as we have some projects what is build with ant script without any version number. I have made some tricks and created Maven repository to use Maven for resolving dependency. But for some reasons result ear file can not be deployed successfully if such files are with version in the name. It is not for spring. Just with our internal library.

Comment: Maven earv plugin allow such configuration. Now I am porting the project from Maven to Gradle.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this @ovasyura ? We "should" be able top just define parameters using the "rename" method, but this does not work for files that are put in the lib folder.